# Remove optional for [String : Any] dictionary keys

Tags: arrays, swift, variables

I have an dictionary like this:

```swift
[
    "Optional(Optional(\"Optional(Optional(\\\"Optional(Optional(\\\\\\\"Optional(Optional(257))\\\\\\\"))\\\"))\"))": "Seçenek 2",
    "Optional(Optional(\"Optional(Optional(\\\"Optional(Optional(\\\\\\\"Optional(Optional(261))\\\\\\\"))\\\"))\"))": "55"
]
```

How remove "Optional" for all keys and use Int values like this:

```swift
["57": "Seçenek 2", "61": "55"]
```

Comment: That `ü` in there looks like a mistake, is it?

Comment: First of all, this is a dictionary, not an array. And these keys are very very strange; something has gone horribly wrong to produce them. You likely have optional values earlier on in the processing that you've let sit around. How did you create this value?

Comment: From where you get this format? API or you create it manually

Comment: I have an [String: Any] dict and ı put an "id" value as string key with string value. I also edit my question.

Comment: @Alexander ı found my mistake. This is mistake for converting Int id to String value. I do this opreations one many time.  Your commend really useful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is awkward to me answer this question, the below code will provides the your requirement

```
var dictionary = [
    "Optional(Optional(\"Optional(Optional(\\\"Optional(Optional(\\\\\\\"Optional(Optional(257))\\\\\\\"))\\\"))\"))": "Seçenek 2",
    "Optional(Optional(\"Optional(Optional(\\\"Optional(Optional(\\\\\\\"Optional(Optional(261))\\\\\\\"))\\\"))\"))": "55"
]

for (key, value) in dictionary{
    let lKey = key.replacingOccurrences(of: "Optional(", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
    dictionary.removeValue(forKey: key)
    dictionary[lKey] = value
}

print(dictionary)
//Output: ["261": "55", "257": "Seçenek 2"]
```

**Suggention**

I suggest you to handle the key value before creating your `dictionary`. User `if let` to unwrap the key and then add key value pair to your `dictionary`

Comment: This is a really janky workaround for a problem that should be solved earlier on. Rather than trying to clean up the dirty data, just don’t make it dirty in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I did mentioned same in my answer too at the suggestion section